# Postgresql Performance: What Is the Best Way to Use pg_timezone_names?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

We use only timestamps without time zone for a global application. However, some things have to be in local times for user convenience. In order for that to work, we have to deal with the conversion from local to UTC, including handling daylight savings. We don't need precision below that of minute.

pg_timezone_names contains everything we need, including the unambiguous long string for time zone name (e.g., 'US/Eastern'), the interval utc_offset, and the boolean is_dst. (I am assuming the latter two values change as dst boundaries are crossed.)

I am trying to figure out the best performance model, assuming we ultimately have millions of users. Here are the options being considered:

1. TZ name string ('US/Eastern') in the table for the location. Every time a time transformation (from local to UTC or back) is needed, we directly call pg_timezone_names for the utc_offset of that time zone. (This is assuming that view is well-indexed.) Index on the string in the location table, of course.
2. Local table time_zones replicating pg_timezone_names, but adding id and boolean in_use columns (and dropping the abbreviation.) Include tz_id in the location table as a foreign key instead of the string.

In the case of a local table, use a procedure that fires around the clock at one minute after every hour over the 26 hours or so that time zones can change, that checks the list of time zones in_use that have just passed two AM Sunday (based on the locally-stored offset,) and calls pg_timezone_names for the updated offset and is_dst values. Trigger updates on the local table check whenever a zone goes into use and makes sure it has the correct values.

The question is whether it is faster to evaluate the indexed string in the location table and then pull the offset from pg_timezone_names every time it is needed, or use a local time_zones table to pull the offset with the FK. I'm thinking the second will be much faster, because it avoids the initial string handling, but it really depends on the speed of the view pg_timezone_names.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this more and discussing with a colleague, I've realized a flaw in the second option above. That option would indeed be quite a bit faster, but it only works if one wishes to pull the current utc_offset for a time zone. If one needs to do it for a timestamp that is not current or a range of timestamps, the built-in postgres view needs to be called, so each timestamp can be called at timezone, which will make the appropriate Daylight Savings conversion for that particular timestamp.

It's slower, but I don't think it can be improved, unless one is only interested in the current timestamp conversion, which is extremely unlikely.

So I am back to the first option, and indexing the time zone string in the local table is no longer necessary, as it would never be searched or sorted on.